# How do we typedef or redefine a templated nested class in the subclass?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
  public:
    template <typename U>
    class Nested { };
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
  public:
    //How do we typedef of redefine Base<T>::Nested?
    using Base<T>::Nested; //This does not work
    using Base<T>::template<typename U> Nested; //Cannot do this either
    typedef typename Base<T>::template<typename U> Nested Nested; //Nope..

    //now we want to use the Nested class here
    template <typename U>
    Class NestedDerived : public Nested { };

    //or like this:
    Nested<int> nestedVar; // obviously does not work
};
```

How to use the templated Nested class in the Derived class? Is this possible to do in current version of C++ standard?

Comment: I don't understand why you are making Nested a 'derived' class, because the Class Derived will inherit the Nested class anyway.

Comment: I want "Nested" class encapsulated in "Base", and "Derived" class can extend or use the "Base::Nested" class.

Comment: In what use-case does `using Base<T>::Nested;` not work?

Comment: @gf: in the last line of my example: `Nested<int> nestedVar;`. I cannot just use/refer to the Nested class by just a word `Nested`, even though I already use `using Base<T>::Nested`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually `using` works as advertised, it just doesn't get rid of the dependent-name issue in the template and it can't currently alias templates directly (will be [fixed in C++0x](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#template-alias)):

```
template <class T>
struct Base {
    template <class U> struct Nested {};
};

template <class T>
struct Derived : Base<T> {
    using Base<T>::Nested;

    // need to prefix Nested with template because
    // it is a dependent template:
    struct X : Base<T>::template Nested<int> {};

    // same here:
    template<class U>
    struct Y : Base<T>::template Nested<U> {};

    // data member, typename is needed here:
    typename Base<T>::template Nested<int> data;
};

void f() { 
    Derived<int>::Nested<int> n; // works fine outside
}
```

There is another possible *gotcha* when using `Derived<T>::Nested` in templates, but again that is a dependent-name issue, not inheritance-related:

```
template<class T>
void g() {
    // Nested is a dependent type and a dependent template, thus
    // we need 'typename' and 'template':
    typedef typename Derived<T>::template Nested<int> NestedInt;
}
```

Just remember that names that depend on template arguments have to be

- prefixed with `typename` if its a dependent type: `typename A<T>::B`
- directly prefixed with `template` if its a dependent template: `A<T>::template f<int>()`
- both if both: `typename A<T>::template B<int>`
- `typename` is illegal in base-class-lists: `template<class T> struct A : B<T>, C<T>::template D<int> {};`

Comment: Can you give example how to use the Nested type for a data member of Derived class? If we still have to use `Base<T>::` , then would the `using Base<T>::Nested` be useless?

Comment: Will do. `using Base<T>::Nested` is not useless though, it is used in `f()` and `g()` - without the `using` declaration, you would have to access `Nested` via `Base` in `f()`.

Comment: Nice answer. +1! Worth pointing out that there is another version `using typename` that is used if `Nested` is a type name (and C++0x will then classify `Nested` in the scope of `Derived` as a type-name (C++03 missed this classification, even tho supporting `using typename`!)). There is, sadly, no way to just write `using Base<T>::template Nested;` to use `Nested` as a template-name in the derived class (neither in C++03 nor in C++0x. In C++0x you would have to use an alias-declaration like you are saying).

Comment: (the defect report for all this is http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#11 )

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

(**EDIT:** added some more lines to show the first template statement. And thanks to Samir Talwar for correcting my formatting!)

```
template <typename T, typename U> 
class Derived : public Base<T> { 
  public: 
    typedef typename Base<T>::template Nested<U> Nested;

    class NestedDerived : public Nested { }; 

    Nested nestedVar;
};
```

Comment: But now users always have to specify a second template argument for `Derived`.

Comment: Yes, and one Derived cannot have more than one type of NestedDerived. It is a serious limitation, but otherwise I don't see any way to have NestedDerived make use of Base::Nested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
  public:
    template <typename U>
    class Nested { };
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
  public:
    //How do we typedef of redefine Base<T>::Nested?
    //using Base<T>::Nested; //This does not work
  //using Base<T>::template<typename U> Nested; //Cannot do this either
  //typedef typename Base<T>::template<typename U> Nested Nested; //Nope..

    //now we want to use the Nested class here
  template <typename U>
  class NestedDerived : public Base<T>::template Nested<U> { };
};

int main()
{
  Base<int>::Nested<double> nested;

  Derived<int>::NestedDerived<double> nested_derived;

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled fine using gcc 4.3.3 on slackware 13

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I am asking. What I want to know is, is it possible to typedef or using the `public Base<T>::template Nested<U>` inside the `Derived` class, because that type will be used in lots of places.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I will try to find a suitable answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure what you want, but you could try.
This compiled on Visual Studio

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
  public:
    template <typename U>
    class Nested { };
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
  public:
    //now we want to use the Nested class here
    template <typename U>
    class NestedDerived : public Nested<U> { };
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
Base<int>::Nested<double> blah2;
Derived<int>::NestedDerived<int> blah;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: this can also use  Derived<int>::Nested<float> blah3;

Comment: What is the difference between what I did and what Craig did? I really didn`t spotted :/

Comment: The problem is you can't use the Nested definition just like that inside Derived class, you have to use a fully qualified name.

Comment: onyl difference i see is this line class  
NestedDerived : public Base<T>::template Nested<U> { };

Comment: The difference is coelhudo's solution compiles on gcc/g++, but still does not answer my question

Comment: can't you just use class NestedDerived : public Base::Nested<U>. The problem is that it runs both Nested and DerivedNested. I'm sure you will find someone here who will have tried this before, personally i haven't needed to yet so i haven't had much of a try.

Comment: I can just move the Nested class out of Base, it is easier that way I guess.